# How to initialize a map of set with a comparison function?

Tags: c++

I have a map where the key is a string and the value is a set of object Msg.

```
class Log{
std::map<std::string, std::set<Msg>> messages;
}

class Msg{
friend class Log;
std::string message;
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point timestamp;
}
```

The key is a phone number and the set contains objects with a text message from that number as well as the message's timestamp. I decided to use a set so that when I insert the messages, it will be sorted by its timestamp which is type time_point. The source is a text file of unsorted messages.

I wrote a comparison function for the set:

```
bool compareTimestamp(const Msg &lhs, const Msg &rhs){
return lhs.timestamp < rhs.timestamp;
}
```

From my research, if this were just a set and not a map of a set, to use the comparison function I would have to define the set like this

```
std::set<Msg, decltype(compareTimestamp)*> set;
```

and initialize the set in the constructor like this:

```
Log() : set(compareTimestamp){}
```

That worked when I tested it by inserting unsorted time_points.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to initialize the set with the comparison function inside of the map.

The map is defined in class Log like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::set<Msg, decltype(compareTimepoint)*>> messages;
```

I tried to initialize this way but it's obviously wrong since it's initializing the map and not the set inside (I tested it anyway and it didn't work):

```
Log() : messages(compareTimepoint){}
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just add an `bool operator<(const Msg& r) const` member function to your `Msg` class and not worry about providing custom comparators to the `set`?

Comment: Or use a `struct` with `operator()` provided so no need to bother with constructor? Like here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/ see `std::set<int,classcomp> fifth;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `set` has its own comparison function.  The `map` doesn't know about the functions of the `set`s under it, or that those functions are all the same.

Since you don't plan to assign any other functions to the function pointer, you can use a comparison class instead. Such a class doesn't need initialization as a pointer does.

```
struct compareTimestamp {
    bool operator () (const Msg &lhs, const Msg &rhs) const {
        return lhs.timestamp < rhs.timestamp;
    }
};

std::map<std::string, std::set<Msg, compareTimestamp>> messages;
```